# How do I list out duplicate entries in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to eliminate duplicate files from a filesystem with around 12,000 decent-size (150+ MB) files. I expect 20-50 duplicates in the set.

Rather than do a checksum on every single file, which is relatively demanding, my idea was to build a hash listing every file and its filesize, eliminate entries where the filesize is unique, and only do a checksum on the remainders, saving a lot of time.

However I'm having a bit of trouble stripping the hash down to just the unique entries. I tried, where `files` is a hash like `super_cool_map.png => 1073741824,`:

```
uniques = files.values.uniq
dupes = files.delete_if do |k,v|
  uniques.include?(v)
end
puts dupes
```

But that only outputs a blank hash. What should I do?

Comment: Give some data input, so that I can show you results step by step.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Your answer is fine. I think using `map` instead of `flat_map` is more useful, it keeps the dupes in a grouped arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this ?

```
# this will give the grouped same size files as an array.
files.group_by(&:last).map { |_, v| v.map(&:first) if v.size > 1 }.compact
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not reverse the mapping? Make the keys the file sizes, and the value a `list` of file names. That way you get "grouping by size" for free.

Then you can filter your hash by using

```
my_hash = {30323 => ["file1", "file2"], 233 => ["file3"]}

filtered = my_hash.select{ |k, v|
  v.size > 1
}

p filtered # prints {30323 => ["file1", "file2"]}
```

Now you have a hash where each key corresponds to a list of files you need to hash and compare to each other.